# Regex: matching for digits excluding some digits at a position

Tags: regex

I have a string which has a pattern, say "xxx.xxx".

So first three are digits, then a . and then 3 more digits.

I want to check if first digit is always 3, and next 2 can be any digits except 30 and 40, rest can be anything.

My regex attempt is:

```
"3[^34][0-9]."
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Which part here is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `^3(?!30|40)\d{2}\.\d{3}$`

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/iCtKnB/1

```
^          matches the start of string
3          matches the number 3
(?!30|40)  checks if the next two numbers are not either 30 or 40
\d{2}      matches two digits if they are not 30 or 40
\.         matches period
\d{3}      matches the next three digits
$
```

Basically this will match any number of your pattern which begins with 3 not followed by 30 or 40 then a dot, followed by another three digits.

In your regex: `"3[^34][0-9]."`

- 3 > This checks the number starts with 3
- [^34] > then the Next digit is not 3 or 4
- [0-9] > followed by one digits which can be 0 to 9
- . > followed by any other char that is not white spaces

So your requirements were not being checked in this regex.

Comment: A few steps less would be a character class inside the negative lookahead instead of alternations: `^3(?![34]0)\d{2}\.\d{3}$`.

Answer (score 2):

In case lookaheads are not supported you can use:

```sh
^3(?:[0-25-9][0-9]|[34][1-9])\.[0-9]{3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkWSR7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
^3(?!30|40)\d{2}\.\d{3}$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` asserts position at start of a line
2. `3` starts with 3
3. `(?!30|40)` negative look ahead to see the following two characters
   do not match 30 or 40 if found successful then `\d{2}` ensures any
   two digits.
4. `\.` means a dot
5. `\d{3}` means 3 digits
6. `$` asserts position at the end of a line

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d15MwA/1)